# Does traffic addressed to one of a Linux system's own interfaces ever leave the system?

Tags: linux, networking, socket

I have two separate servers running on the same port on a Linux system, one binded to the loopback interface, and the other to the public Ethernet interface. If I connect a client on that system to the public socket, is the system smart enough to keep the traffic internal to itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No the data never leaves the box when it's addressing an IP address that's assigned to a local interface.

You can convince yourself of this fact by using `traceroute` to confirm.

#### Example

Here's my wireless NIC on my Fedora 19 system.

```
$ ip -4 addr show wlp3s0 | grep inet
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp3s0
```

It's assigned the IP address 192.168.1.20. If we `traceroute` this IP:

```
$ traceroute 192.168.1.20
traceroute to 192.168.1.20 (192.168.1.20), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  greeneggs.bubba.net (192.168.1.20)  0.041 ms  0.013 ms  0.013 ms
```

Notice we never leave the box. It's a single hop so we're staying local to the system.

Comment: Follow-up question: [what if I want to send the packet externally](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106291/send-a-packet-over-the-network-even-when-its-target-is-the-local-host)?

Comment: actually this does not test whether the packet physically appears on the wire. you'll need to run a packet sniffer on the hub or from a different host on the same subnet and see if it shows up.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - yes it does. If the packet egressed from the system we would've seen the IP of the router/switch when we performed the traceroute given how traceroutes work.

Comment: won't a traceroute stop once it gets a reply from the target? in this case it won't record the ip of the router. it stops when it gets a response from eth0. but this still doesn't tell us whether the packet physically appeared on the wire.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - traceroute induces ever node b/w the originator and the target to send a timeout reply packet.

Comment: @slm. yes. but let's say it receives a packet from eth0 before receiving one from the switch. It has done its job, it's not going to report the switch ...

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - if you have a new Q I encourage you to ask on the main site.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - traceroute knows all the packets that it's put inflight, so I would expect that it's going to keep track of them for accounting purposes and reflect this in it's output. Running `traceroute` through `strace` will show you what's going on BTW.

Comment: @slm. Your choice of terminology "expect" says all. You don't know. I don't know. Only way to verify is to sniff the wire.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez - Don't read so much into my choice of terminology. As stated, you can confirm with `strace`. That's what I did here, so I'm highly confident that it does not. If you truly wanted to know a review of the source code would confirm as well.